# Java Stream API - Custom infinite source

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to create a stream of elements with an ability to add elements into it after its creation. I haven't found any info about possibility of creating infinite streams with custom source.

For example: I want to fill stream with new bytes from audio stream. On the output I get `Stream<Byte>`. And I should have a mechanism to be able to fill stream in runtime with bytes.

Comment: `Stream.generate` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @shmosel edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily prepend a given element to a Stream by invoking the static Stream.concat() method:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Stream<Integer> newStream = Stream.concat(Stream.of(6), stream);
```

To append, just revert them:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Stream<Integer> newStream = Stream.concat(stream, Stream.of(6));
```

`Stream` does not have an idea of what indexs are. Therefore, you must collect the stream to a `List`, insert the element at the preferred index you want, and produce the stream again with `List.stream()`:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 6);
List<Integer> list = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
list.add(4, 5);
Stream<Integer> newStream = list.stream();
```

Note that Stream can represent infinite sequences so sometimes you may never get to your new element in collections.

Comment: It's close to what I want to do, but stream cannot have any reassigning. Thus I return my stream I need to add elements into it without changing any references. What about `Stream.generate`, might it help?

Comment: @VaniaShows Stream.generate may not be what you need. It accepts a Supplier unfortunately. You cannot really create different objects from the same supplier, so Stream.generate is designed for generating random elements. Try to look at [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-)